# Google Chrome Inspect Element : I don't have the "Application" tab

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, session-cookies, web-inspector

When I use the inspect element in Google Chrome, I don't have the "Application" tab to see the site cookies. Why ?

[My inspect element of Google Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywIbG.jpg)

Thank you !

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Go on 3dots(...)  click on "other tools" and look for it in the menu.